# How do i extract some particular words from each line?

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed, grep

The text file has many lines of these sort , i want to extract the words after **/videos** till **.mp4** and the very last number ( shown in bold ) and output each filtered line in a separate file

```
https://videos-a.jwpsrv.com/content/conversions/7kHOkkQa/videos/**S4KWZTyt-32313922.mp4**.m3u8?hdnts=exp=1592315851~acl=*/S4KWZTyt-32313922.mp4.m3u8~hmac=83f4674e6bf2576b070c716a3196cb6a30f35737827ee69c8cf7e0c57a196e51 **1**
```

*Lets say for example the text file content is ..*

```
https://videos-a.jwpsrv.com/content/conversions/7kHOkkQa/videos/JajSfbVN-32313922.mp4.m3u8?hdnts=exp=1592315891~acl=*/JajSfbVN-32313922.mp4.m3u8~hmac=d3ca7bd5b233a531cfe242d17d2ea0c0167b41b90fff6459e433700ffc969d69 19

https://videos-a.jwpsrv.com/content/conversions/7kHOkkQa/videos/Qs3xZqcv-32313922.mp4.m3u8?hdnts=exp=1592315940~acl=*/Qs3xZqcv-32313922.mp4.m3u8~hmac=c30e2082bf748a6b4d1621c1d33a95319baa61798775e9da8856041951cf5233 20
```

*The output should be*

```
JajSfbVN-32313922.mp4 19
Qs3xZqcv-32313922.mp4 20
```

Comment: I would suggest not using regexes, but use your language of choice to parse the URLs into their components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the below regex:

```
.*\/videos\/(.*?mp4).*?(?<= )(\d+)
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

> **`.*`** - Matching everything before `\videos`.
>
> **`\/videos\/`** - Matching videos literally.
>
> **`(.*?mp4)`** - Represents a capturing group lazily matching everything before `mp4`.
>
> **`.*?`** - Greedily matches everything before the occurrence of digits.
>
> **`(\d+)`** - Represents second capturing group matching the numbers at the end as required by you.

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/WjpbxD/3)

---

[image: Pictorial representation]

**Command line implementation in linux:**

```
cat regea.txt | perl -ne 'print "$1 $2\n" while /.*\/videos\/(.*?mp4).*?(?<= )(\d+)/g;'> out.txt
```

You can find the sample implementation of the above command in [**here.**](https://repl.it/@mAndY80SS/ToughHiddenExperiment)

Answer (score 1):

The proposed regex is probably a better solution, but I'll leave a Python solution that writes each filtered line in a separate file. This script works if every line in the file is like that.

```
with open("my_file.txt","r") as FILE:
    lines=FILE.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        num=line.split(" ")[1]
        newline=line.split("videos")[2]
        newline=newline[1:]
        new=newline.split(".")[0:2]
        with open(new[0],"w") as f:
            f.write(new[0]+"."+new[1]+" "+num.strip())
            f.close
```